# App android can not Play video with video in USB OTG

Tags: android, usb-otg

I make app android to interact with USB OTG, I can read info all file in USB OTG, but i can not play video in USB OTG, but i can play video in SD. help me. Thanks All
my code:

```
 fun openVideo(path: String){
    val viewIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    val file = File(path)

    viewIntent.setDataAndType(
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            file
        ), "video/*"
    )
    viewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    context?.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(viewIntent, null))
}
```

Comment: `val file = File(path)` Please tell the used value for `path`.

Comment: `but i can play video in SD` What do you mean? From a removable micro sd card? Dont think so. Please explain.